# Why won't my VB 6.0 app compile?

Tags: vb6

I have been tasked with adding a feature to a 10 year old vb 6.0 app. At first I was getting the following error when I tried to create the exe:

"Can't find the project or library"

It then listed as MISSING: Crystal Reports 8.5 Standard Wizard Library

So I got ahold of that dll and put it in system32 and then, in the Reference popup, mapped it to the dll. However I still get the same error message and it points to the same dll although "MISSING" has been removed.

Comment: what line of code is it highlighting when it throws the error?

Comment: Just an FYI: in general, the line of code that the IDE highlights in the event of a missing library is usually not even remotely relevant to the library that is missing. For example, you might be missing said Crystal Reports library, but the IDE might highlight a line of code that is displaying a message box. Therefore I wouldn't rely on gleaning any useful information from the line the IDE stops on.

Answer (score 1):

there may two entries in the registry causing the issue, possibly one in a deleted directory.  I'd recommend cleaning your registry with something like [ccleaner](http://www.piriform.com/ccleaner) and then try registering it again.  VB6 will occassionally hold on to bad reg keys.

You might check also check the exe/dlls with a tool like Dependency Walker to see if there is a missing secondary component of the report tool that is missing: http://download.cnet.com/Dependency-Walker/3000-2086_4-10052198.html

Comment: Ideally you should run the *install* provided by the tool vendor.

Comment: Agree with @MarkJ. The DLL in question also needs to be registered if it was simply copied to the development machine, but the installer will take care of that (and any other dependencies). However, if for some reason you don't have and/or can't get a Crystal 8.5 installation CD, the DLL would need to be registered with *regsvr32* at a bare minimum for VB to have any hope of finding it.

Answer (score 0):

I inherited the maintenance of an app that uses CR 8.5 too. In the InnoSetup installer the following .dll's are specified. I think you need them all! Mind the installation directories! Some go to Sytem 32 ({sys}) others go to Windows\Crystal

```
;Crystal Report files
Source: CR\Crystl32.ocx; DestDir: {sys}; Flags: regserver sharedfile
Source: CR\mfcans32.dll; DestDir: {sys}; Flags: sharedfile
Source: CR\crpe32.dll; DestDir: {sys}; Flags: sharedfile
Source: CR\Crpaig80.dll; DestDir: {sys}; Flags: sharedfile
Source: CR\Implode.dll; DestDir: {sys}; Flags: sharedfile
Source: CR\msvcp60.dll; DestDir: {sys}; Flags: restartreplace sharedfile
Source: CR\Exlate32.dll; DestDir: {sys}; Flags: sharedfile
Source: CR\p2bdao.dll; DestDir: {sys}; Flags: sharedfile
Source: CR\p2ctdao.dll; DestDir: {sys}; Flags: sharedfile
Source: CR\p2irdao.dll; DestDir: {sys}; Flags: sharedfile
Source: CR\u2ddisk.dll; DestDir: {win}\Crystal
Source: CR\u2fhtml.dll; DestDir: {win}\Crystal
Source: CR\u2fsepv.dll; DestDir: {win}\Crystal
Source: CR\u2ftext.dll; DestDir: {win}\Crystal
Source: CR\u2fwordw.dll; DestDir: {win}\Crystal
Source: CR\u2fxls.dll; DestDir: {win}\Crystal
Source: CR\u2lsamp1.dll; DestDir: {win}\Crystal
;end Crystal Report files
```